# How to enable /disable popout option in youtube video

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, activex, youtube-api

how can i enable/disable the youtube pop out option when you right click on youtube video on IE. is there any perticular API i need to use to achieve this plz help me

Answer (score 0):

The recent version of Youtube blocked lots of thinks, like block downloading using Chrome Apps,

Try in IE 8, its works for me